# Connectedness & HATEOAS

Tags: rest, hateoas

It is said that in a well defined RESTful system, the clients only need to know the root URI or few well known URIs and the client shall discover all other links through these initial URIs. I do understand the benefits (decoupled clients) from this approach but the downside for me is that the client needs to discover the links each time it tries access something i.e given the following hierarchy of resources:

```
/collection1
collection1
  |-sub1
    |-sub1sub1
 |-sub1sub1sub1
         |-sub1sub1sub1sub1
    |-sub1sub2
  |-sub2
    |-sub2sub1
    |-sub2sub2
  |-sub3
    |-sub3sub1
    |-sub3sub2
```

If we follow the "*Client only need to know the root URI*" approach, then a client shall only be aware of the root URI i.e. /collection1 above and the rest of URIs should be discovered by the clients through hypermedia links. I find this cumbersome because each time a client needs to do a GET, say on sub1sub1sub1sub1, should the client first do a GET on /collection1 and the follow link defined in the returned representation and then do several more GETs on sub resources to reach the desired resource? or is my understanding about connectedness completely wrong?

Best regards,
Suresh

Comment: Just the REST service is stateless, the client is not. So the client can remember the previous resources, their URL-s, etc... for example by a nested navigation menu...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will run into this mismatch when you try and build a REST api that does not match the flow of the user agent that is consuming the API.

Consider when you run a client application, the user is always presented with some initial screen.  If you match the content and options on this screen with the root representation then the available links and desired transitions will match nicely.  As the user selects options on the screen, you can transition to other representations and the client UI should be updated to reflect the new representation.

If you try and model your REST API as some kind of linked data repository and your client UI as an independent set of transitions then you will find HATEOAS quite painful.

Comment: painful isn't necessarily true: I have just this, a hierarchy of collections of items, and the client, when it starts, it drills down one or two levels, and drills down to a specific path (the path that the client used to have when it shut down).  The client's cache is persistent, so all the requests are conditional, and very rarely do new representations go over the wire, and the refresh can be done asynchronously in the background by working entirely off the cache.

Comment: and I agree that modeling the "API" as the client application's requirements makes for an effective session, but I guess the point is that often an API should cater to many clients, not just that one client.

Comment: @mogsie  It may be possible in many cases to build an API for multiple clients, however I think in most cases it is far more efficient to build an API for a specific case. Serendipitous reuse is what REST is intended to provide, not necessarily planned reuse.

Comment: that's true.  Let's say twitter built a **truly** RESTful API; they would probably be well off by using a real or hypothetical client when desigining the API.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's right that the client application should traverse the links, but once it's discovered a resource, there's nothing wrong with keeping a reference to that resource and using it for a longer time than one request.  If your client has the possibility of remembering things permanently, it can do so.

consider how a web browser keeps its bookmarks.  You probably have maybe ten or a hundred bookmarks in the browser, and you probably found some of these deep in a hierarchy of pages, but the browser dutifully remembers them without requiring remembering the path it took to find them.

A more rich client application could remember the URI of sub1sub1sub1sub1 and reuse it if it still works.  It's likely that it still represents the same thing (it ought to).  If it no longer exists or fails for any other client reason (4xx) you could retrace your steps to see if you can find a suitable replacement.

And of course what Darrel Miller said :-)

Comment: I like your analogy here. There's this idea where everything is linked together and what's not linked can't be reached. Google in that sense became the root of all navigations but people save shortcuts (bookmarks) all the time. However if you're not in google then you basically do not exist.

Comment: Thanks.  Or, to be more precise: If there's no path from Google to a page, it doesn't exist.  Somewhat like the riddle: "If a tree falls in a forest and nobody is there to hear it; does it make any noise?"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that that's the strict requirement. From how I understand it, it is legal for a client to access resources directly and start from there. The important thing is that you do not do this for state transitions, i.e. do not automatically proceed with /foo2 after operating on /foo1 and so forth. Retrieving /products/1234 initially to edit it seems perfectly fine. The server could always return, say, a redirect to /shop/products/1234 to remain backwards compatible (which is desirable for search engines, bookmarks and external links as well).